# Time function alternative to concatenate 3 cells into HH:MM:SS

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula, libreoffice-calc, calc

i wonder if there is another excel fuction i can use to combine 3 numbers into time formated as (hh:mm:ss).

The time function works great but example below shows a problem that it cant go beyond 24h.

Ive tried to reformat the cells as [HH]:MM:SS but this sadly dont seem to work. Ive found information online that this is due to a restriction for the time function.

**Formula:**

```
=TIME(

   Hour:
   FLOOR((20/3 + (M7 - 20) / (3 * (IF(M7 < 20,ts_0,Y7)+Z7)))), 

   Minute:
   ROUND(MOD(((20/3) + ((M7 - 20) / (3 * (
   IF(M7 < 20,ts_0,Y7) + Z7))) - FLOOR((20/3 + (M7 - 20) / (3 * (
   IF(M7 < 20,ts_0,Y7)+Z7))))) * 60;60)),

   Second:
   ROUND(MOD(((20/3) + ((M7 - 20) / (3 * (
   IF(M7 < 20,ts_0,Y7) + Z7))) - FLOOR((20/3 + (M7 - 20) / (3 * (
   IF(M7 < 20,ts_0,Y7)+Z7))))) * 3600;60))

)

M7= (Int) Some distance, 15 or 25 for example.
Z7= (Percent) Some percentage, 5% or 25 for example.
Y7= (Float) For ex. 1,0
ts_0= (Float) For ex. 1,0
```

**Problem:**

Example good Result: 01:29:27 (01,29,27)

```
Expected Output: 01:29:27
Actual Output: 01:29:27
```

Example bad Result: 01:27:17 (25,27,17)

```
Expected Output: 25:27:17
Actual Output: 01:27:17
```

Comment: Using concatenate with text does not seem to work,

A1: 17 
B1: 42
C1: 18

=CONCATENATE(":",,TEXT(A1;"hh"),TEXT(B1;"mm"),TEXT(C1,"ss"))

Expected Output: 17:42:18
Actual Output: 00:02:35

Comment: You have left `Y7` out of your list of "what the variables mean/are"

Comment: Thanks, i edited main post.

Comment: Please do not put solutions in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula seems awfully complicated.

Try:  `=A2/24+B2/1440+C2/86400`

Custom Format the cell as `[hh]:mm:ss`

[image]

Comment: This indeed worked wonders. Not that it looks any cleaner for me as i included all formulas in 1 string. haha. Thanks! :)

=floor((20/3 + (M55 - 20) / (3 * (IF(M55 < 20,ts_0,T55)+U55))))/24+floor(mod(((20/3) + ((M55 - 20) / (3 * (IF(M55 < 20,ts_0,T55) + U55))) - floor((20/3 + (M55 - 20) / (3 * (IF(M55 < 20,ts_0,T55)+U55))))) * 60,60))/1440+round(mod(((20/3) + ((M55 - 20) / (3 * (IF(M55 < 20,ts_0,T55) + U55))) - floor((20/3 + (M55 - 20) / (3 * (IF(M55 < 20,ts_0,T55)+U55))))) * 3600,60))/86400

Comment: @Gobban Glad I was able to help.  I was only answering the question you posed about ***combine 3 numbers into time*** and being able to have more than 24 hrs . The three numbers are in `A2:C2` in my example.  How you derive those three numbers, however, is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution!

=TEXT(CONCATENATE(':',,A1,B1;C1);'[HH]:MM:SS')

Then change each cell reference (A1,B1,C1) to your formula.

So for me it looks like this,

Function text:

```
=TEXT(
```

Function concatenate:

```
=concatenate(":",,
```

A1:

```
FLOOR((20/3 + (M7 - 20) / (3 * (IF(M7 < 20,ts_0,Y7)+Z7)))),
```

B1:

```
 FLOOR(MOD(((20/3) + ((M7 - 20) / (3 * (
 IF(M7 < 20,ts_0,Y7) + Z7))) - FLOOR((20/3 + (M7 - 20) / (3 * (
 IF(M7 < 20,ts_0,Y7)+Z7))))) * 60;60)),
```

C1:

```
ROUND(MOD(((20/3) + ((M7 - 20) / (3 * (
IF(M7 < 20,ts_0,Y7) + Z7))) - FLOOR((20/3 + (M7 - 20) / (3 * (
IF(M7 < 20,ts_0,Y7)+Z7))))) * 3600;60))
```

concatenate end parenthases:

```
)
```

text ending and formating:

```
;"[HH]:MM:SS")
```

**Note,**
Important to include hour format within brackets if you want to go beyond 24h.

Comment: Wont be able to do any futher calculations with it so the problem remains.

Comment: Just add Zero, to convert it back into a number, then apply the Custom Number Format to the cell.

Comment: Thanks, that might also work. I edited the post with another working solution.